# How can i remove uploaded image to replace with another image in primefaces <p:fileUpload>?

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I am just a beginner in primefaces and I just want to know how I can remove the uploaded file. Another one is that within `<p:fileUpload>` tag, can I show the uploaded file for update or remove? Is this supported by `<p:fileUpload>`? My uploaded file is not yet on the disk or in the database but still is an object. My code is as below. Please help me or give me some idea.

This is **fileupload.xhtml**

```
    <h:outputLabel value="Choose Image:" />
        <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{ManageProductCode.handleFileUpload}" mode= "advanced"
            sizeLimit="3000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" id="MyAttachment" fileLimit="1" 
            required="true" requiredMessage="Image Is Require."/>

    <br/>
```

This is my backing bean. That is just assigning value to persist into database.

```
private UploadedFile uploadFile;
public UploadedFile getUploadFile() {
    return uploadFile;
}

public void setUploadFile(UploadedFile uploadFile) {
    this.uploadFile = uploadFile;
}

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event){
    uploadFile = event.getFile();
    System.out.println("UploadFileName is" + uploadFile.getFileName());

    byte[]image = event.getFile().getContents();
    productCode.setImage(image);
}
```

This is my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```